# How does the ring structure $10\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Now the set of integers $10\mathbb{Z}=0,10,-10,20,-20,..$ and $5\mathbb{Z}=0,+5,-5,+10,-10,...$ .How does $10\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ will look like -$10\mathbb{Z},5+10\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $A/B$ defines a ring only if $A$ is a ring and $B$ is an ideal in $A$. This is not the case here. $5\Bbb Z$ isn't even a subset of $10\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Perhaps, you meant $5\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ instead, right? You might have "accidentally" switched the order of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotient ring $\frac{I}{J} $ is possible iff J is an ideal of the ring I. Here in this case, $5\mathbb{Z} $ is not an ideal of $10\mathbb{Z} $ , even $5\mathbb{Z} $ is not a subring of $10\mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: But $10\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please see the question!

Comment: If op do the edit, then we can go for that!